# Classic Email Letterhead

Tags: email-template, document, letterhead

Is there a way to create professional letterheads similar to Classic Email Letterhead with Lightning?  If not is there a way to use a file in the Classic Email Template instead [image]of a document?

Comment: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_email_templates_letterheads.htm Are you just looking for steps on creating a letterhead to use in lightning email templates?

Comment: Thanks - I will try it out to see if it produces the same results as Classic Email Letterhead

Comment: I tried out the Lightning Letterhead & it doesn't give the same professional look that the Classic Letterhead does.  For example, I can center a logo on the page, but the body of the email isn't left and right aligned with padding like the Classic Email Letterhead.

Comment: Is there anything else you're looking to accomplish other than the left/right padding that you'd be looking for to be considered more professional?

Comment: This is essentially it.  It just looks bad with a logo centered in the middle and the text left aligned.  I am might not be describing it well.  When using the Classic Letterhead, the mailings look like they have come from something like MailChimp or Constant Contact.  When using a Lightning template with/without letterhead, it just looks like a regular email with a centered logo stuck at the top.  Doesn't look good.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what you're looking for so an answer can be given. It might help to have some screenshots with fake emails to show what you're saying. I'm not sure I completely understand as couldn't you just center the text so it's not left aligned?

Comment: Please see updated question for example of Classic email that I am trying to duplicate in Lightning.